# Uploading a csv to S3 with AWS SDK v3 getting partial data issue

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When trying to upload a csv file to s3 using 's3Client.send()', only first line of data is uploaded. While setting endpointUrl in testing environment then this issue occurred. But the file generated locally seems to be alright(with endpointUrl empty).

```
async uploadFileToS3(params) {
    const { s3Params, inputFileName, outputFileName } = params;

    logger.info(`uploadFileToS3 params ${JSON.stringify(params)}`);  
    const invocationParams = {
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId: s3Params.accessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: s3Params.secretAccessKey,
      },
      region: K.IMPORT.S3_REGION,
    };
   
    const uploadParams = {
      Bucket: s3Params.bucketName,
      Key: `${s3Params.uploadPath}/${outputFileName}`,
      Body: createReadStream(inputFileName),
    };

    if (s3Params.endpointUrl) {
      invocationParams.endpoint = s3Params.endpointUrl;
    }

    const s3Client = new S3Client(invocationParams);
    
    const resp = await s3Client.send(new PutObjectCommand(uploadParams));
    logger.info(`uploadFileToS3 SUCCESS ${JSON.stringify(resp)}`);

    return params;
  }
```